# Android hide sub menu item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation menu drawer that is set up with multiple groups and menus like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Participant">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_new"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="@string/nav_new" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_start"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="@string/nav_start" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_delete"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                    android:title="@string/nav_delete" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Sensors">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_raw"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                    android:title="@string/nav_raw" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_graphs"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:title="@string/nav_graphs" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I'm trying to set one of the submenu items to invisible. Lets say I want to hide the Start item. I have tried doing that with:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
navMenu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
```

I expected it to hide the second item (Start) but instead it just hides the entire second menu group.

Whats the correct way to get a sub item like this? Or am I just incorrectly laying out my menu xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
navMenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(1).setVisible(false);
```

Comment: navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);